# Сохранение картинок из ссылок при парсинге Jsoup'ом

Tags: java, android

Вообщем есть идея сделать возможность скачивать нужную информацию на свой телефон и хранить ее, чтобы она была доступна даже без сети.
Вообщем, как вижу это я: 
Скачиваю HTML страницу с помощью jsoup библиотеки и сохраняю ее в string. С помощью elements выбираю ссылки на картинки, а также с помощью тех же элементов даю примерный путь к сохранению картинки, к примеру "/stat/1.png"
Так вот проблема в том, как скачать их и сохранить в папку с приложением по такому шаблону: путь к папке с приложением + "/stat/1.png" (то, что я получаю при парсинге). 
Как это можно реализовать? Помогите пожалуйста, никогда не сталкивался со скачиванием и сохранением просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте отечественную разработку [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). После её настройки согласно инструкции по ссылке процесс загрузки будет выглядеть так:

```
String imageUri = "ТУТ_АДРЕС_КАРТИНКИ_В_ИНТЕРНЕТЕ";
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Можно пустым оставить и ничего тут не делать
    }
});
```

Библиотека поместит загруженное изображение в кэш, и когда вам понадобится её отобразить вы сможете просто вызвать:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

чтобы из кэша установить вашу картинку в `ImageView`

---

Подобных библиотек множество. Из последних - [fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) от лицоКниги.

Comment: Тоже об этом думал, но а если человек кеш почистит, тогда они же удалятся, как я понимаю?

Comment: При стирании данных удаляется содержимое внутренней папки приложения. Вы можете указать библиотке папку для кэша в другом месте, в корне девайса, например, и тогда удалить их можно будет только чрез файловый менеджер. Но лучше так не делать. Юзеры будут недовольны.

Comment: Так я не пойму) Кеш стирается или нет, когда, к примеру, CleanMaster запустить или другими утилитами по отчистке мусора

Comment: Насколько мне известно они все стирают только внутренние файлы приложения. Куда вы помнстите кэш они узнать не смогут

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, будем экспериментировать, и еще вопрос, а если захочу удалить из кеша эти картинки сам, ну тобиш пользователь захотел удалить из локального хранилища сохраненные данные, то можно это осуществить?)

Comment: Да, можно. Вы будете знать путь к вашей папке с кэшем и сможете циклом пробежаться по всем в ней файлам и их удалить)